# Html form input button with default OS style: How to make it glow\light up?

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, button

So having `<li><FORM><INPUT class="eButton" type="button" value="Ole"></FORM></li>` is it possible to make such class glow\lightup as if it notifies user about something, while it shall have default OS look on Linux, Mac and Windows?

So let us look onto simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/uDdbq/10/ what I need is simulate mouse over recursivly with out mouse over and with some other, not default color (yellow for example)

Like glowing from this state:

[image]

to this

[image]

again and again.

Comment: "Glow" how? Inside? Outside? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you link to an example of this glowing effect?

Comment: **[What] I need is simulate mouse over recursivly with out mouse over...** based on interaction with what elements? On what condition do you want this to happen?

Comment: @David: minitech got it correctly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tint it without a hack (overlaying a semi-transparent element), and with the varying button styles across browsers, there's no way to get the border radius perfect, unfortunately.

If you're OK with an imperfect glow, here's how: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/vXKrE/ (click the button to activate its glow)

Add some error-handling in the JavaScript and it actually degrades gracefully since the background has no effect on browsers that don't support `rgba`.

Comment: @Kabumbus: It's all in the jsFiddle I just edited my post to add, copy that JavaScript to the page on which you want to use the effect, add the CSS as well, add a `<button-overlay></button-overlay>` element to every button to which you need to apply this effect, and finally call `glow(theButton)` (where *theButton* is a reference to the button element) once every second for as many times as you want it to blink.

Comment: @Kabumbus: Also, you have to use a `<button>` element instead of an `<input type="button" />`. There's not much difference though, just put the value inside the tag.

Comment: Is it possible to make it repeat? Is it possible to make it on all class of buttons? Grate I love this thing!)))

Comment: @Kabumbus: Here's how to make it repeat: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/vXKrE/1/ I don't know about making it apply to `<input type="button">` or `<input type="submit">` but I'll give it a try (it's harder to stretch to the right size).

Comment: Btw try it on FireFox... 3, 4, 5 does not matter... FF works incorrectly) Chrome and Opera and IE (tested on IE 9 ) on windows are super grate)))

Comment: @Kabumbus: Oh, you mean it's not edge-to-edge? Nothing that can be done about that.

Answer (score 1):

You could give it a colored box-shadow on focus:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 3px yellow;
```

Obviously works with browsers that support box-shadow